# php version on server 12.04LTS

Tags: 12.04, php

Php 5.3 is end of life and not receiving security updates. Can someone confirm that 5.5 or 5.6 will work properly on Ubuntu Server 12.04? Thanks.

Comment: What does "work properly" mean? BTW 5.5 reached EOL this month.

Comment: OK, change that to 5.6. (I know 5.5 went EOL on 7/10.) 5.3 isn't safe as far as I know because it isn't receiving updates and there are some vulnerabilities. I'm trying to get someone to update to 5.6. Is there any reason why they can't update to 5.6?

Comment: Again... What's "properly". PHP packages from PPA will run properly, but whether all old scripts that haven't been updated in ages will run that's entirely different question.

Comment: Well, I guess that is the point. If they are trying to avoid updating their scripts in order to stick with 5.3 I consider that not good practice... So, let me rephrase: There is nothing inherent in 12.04 that would prevent them from updating to 5.6, correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS will run PHP 5.6 or even PHP 7.0 just fine if you use PHP PPA from ppa:ondrej/php. The user scripts will have to be updated though as there were some changes between PHP 5.3 and 5.4. Update guides are available directly at the PHP website.

NOTE: I'll update with more direct links when I get to computer. Meanwhile just search here on AU for more thorough guides. (to editors, if you are editing, please remove this note.)

Comment: Thank you! That is what I suspected but I was looking for confirmation.